when I use LookupActivity and call deleteRecordSp it somehow rollsback the deleted record?
I encountered an issue while using Azure Synapse's Lookup Activity to call a stored procedure that deletes records from a table. Despite the activity completing almost instantaneously, no records were deleted. Initially, I suspected that the problem might be related to permissions. However, the stored procedure sometimes works when triggered manually, but not always.
I verified that the PostgreSQL grants are correctly configured, and when I manually execute the stored procedure with the following command, it successfully deletes the records:
SQL
CALL deleteSPrecords();SELECT 1 AS output;

Has anyone else faced a similar issue or have insights on why this inconsistency might occur

Could you please provide the stored procedure script?

Here is the sample stored procedure to delete rows in table:
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteSPrecords(employee_id INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    DELETE FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = employee_id;
$$;

Called the stored procedure from Lookup activity with below query:
CALL deleteSPrecords(4);SELECT 1 AS output;


It is deleting the row successfully as shown below:

You can check below instructions:
Transaction Handling: Ensure that the stored procedure includes proper transaction handling. Sometimes, if the transaction is not committed, the changes might not be visible. You can add explicit BEGIN and COMMIT statements within the stored procedure to ensure the transaction is committed.
Stored Procedure Logic: Review the logic within the stored procedure to ensure there are no conditions or logic that might cause it to skip the deletion under certain circumstances. For example, if there are conditional statements or checks within the stored procedure, ensure they are working as expected.
